# Entity Framework Core: Custom Linq methods for querying view models from DbContext

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing a .NET Core web API using .NET Core 2.0 and Entity Framework 2.0. The project and especially the amount of view models keep growing and the complexity becomes more intense (more nested models). The main point for my question is that the view models share a lot of sub models.

And I bet I don't use the correct keywords for googling because I can't find what I want to know.

Currently I query and map them (according to some defined logic) directly via the DbContext (each time aka for each view model). For example:

```
List<MyViewModel1> items = await MyDbContext.MyDbModel1
  .Where(dbm1 => dbm1.SomeValue > 10)
  .Select
     (
        dbm1 => new MyViewModel1 
        {
            ValueName = dbm1.SomeValue,
            NestedModel1 = new NestedViewModel1 
            {
               SomeValue1 = dbm1.OtherTableModel1.Value1,
               SomeValue2 = dbm1.OtherTableModel1.Value2
            },
            NestedModel2 = (!dbm1.OtherTableModel2Id.HasValue) ? null :
                  new NestedViewModel2 
                  {
                     SomeCalculatedValue = dbm1.OtherTableModel2.Value1 + dbm1.OtherTableModel2.Value2,
                     SomeOtherValue = dbm1.OtherTableModel2.Value3
                   }
       }
   )
   .ToListAsync();
```

Now the problem is: NestedViewModel2 (the one with the calculation) is attached to multiple view models and so far I write this calculation every time in the same way as above (for MyViewModel1, MyViewModel2, MyViewModel3,...). And as it is, requirements change regulary. And each time the requirements change I have to spot all places in my growing code and fix the calculation on multiple places.

That approach does not follow DRY (don't repeat yourself).

But I can't find information if it is possible (and how) to write some custom linq extension methods (which entity framework will understand for the linq to SQL conversion) like:

- SelectViewModel1WithValueGreaterThan(this DbSet, int greaterThan)
- SelectViewModel2List(this DbSet)
- SelectViewModel3Details(this DbSet)

and especially have the Nested Models select in one place (that can get called from the above methods).

- SelectNestedModel1(???)
- SelectNestedModel2(???)

Any hints for me how to pack those queries into custom linq extension methods so the code follows the DRY principle and can be reused?

Comment: I am not quite sure if it would fit in your code base but couldn't you implement a nestedviewmodelFactory in order to init your viewmodels and capsulate your calculations? ([Factory Design Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx))

Comment: Take a look at [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/), especially [NeinLinq.EntityFrameworkCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#neinlinqentityframeworkcore): *"NeinLinq.EntityFrameworkCore provides helpful extensions for using LINQ providers such as Entity Framework that support only a minor subset of .NET functions, reusing functions, rewriting queries, even making them null-safe, and building dynamic queries using translatable predicates and selectors.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at a mapping framework to map the DB Entities to the ViewModels. For example, we are using [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) to achieve this.

This allows you to define the mappings centrally and reuse them. This should simplify most of the code, because the logic you want to refactor is in the `select` part of the query.

```
MappingConfig.CreateMap<MyDbModel1, MyViewModel1>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.ValueName, o => o.MapFrom(ent => ent.SomeValue))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.NestedModel1, o => o.MapFrom(ent => ent.OtherTableModel1));

MappingConfig.CreateMap<OtherTableModel1, NestedViewModel1>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.SomeValue1 , o => o.MapFrom(ent => ent.Value1))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.SomeValue2 , o => o.MapFrom(ent => ent.Value2));

var items = Mapper.Map<MyViewModel1[]>(MyDbContext.MyDbModel1.Where(dbm1 => dbm1.SomeValue > 10));
```

Comment: And the last call where you assign to var items will work with loading the related data using EF Core so the data from the other tables is attached? If yes: dann schaun wirs uns mal an

Comment: Yes, related entities will be mapped too (usually through lazy loading). There are also extensions that optimize the projection from the ORM, see [docs.automapper.org - Queryable Extensions](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#)

Comment: You'll have to choose where your logic will sit. If your logic will sit in application then you should use smth like Automapper and this is it, you can't do more than this. Another architectural approach is to project what you need from database and to have some models mapped to what you're projecting. Example (not tested in EF Core, but tested in EF): create database views (those can be optimized by DBAs) and map those views to models (EF code-first).